# Does anyone know for sure what was written in the tablets mentioned in Exodus 16:34?

Tags: exodus, law

Exodus 16:34 in some bible versions mentions some tablets and I was just wondering if anyone knew what was on those tablets.

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of : https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/18699/what-was-written-on-the-stone-tablets?rq=1 - which was not closed for being "opinion-based".

Comment: I agree with Elika Kohen. A good answer here would provide "facts" to support the "opinion" being expressed. ALL answers to ALL questions  are opinion-based!!!

Comment: @elikakohen Your edit to the question needs to be rolled back. Exodus 16:34 speaks of הָעֵדֻ֖ת ("the Testimony" - [Strong's H5715 - \`eduwth](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/Lexicon/Lexicon.cfm?strongs=H5715&t=KJV)), which Gesenius says is "*especially used of the decalogue*". So clarification needs to be made on the appearance of הָעֵדֻ֖ת in Exodus 16:34.

Comment: @dpb2020 - Feel free to chime in!  Hopefully, we can get this reopened.

Comment: @elikakohen I believe the OP's dilemma concerns הָעֵדֻ֖ת, which commentators, as indicated by freethinker (first responder), have tried to address. So, it might be better to edit the question to identify the problem caused by the appearance of the word  הָעֵדֻ֖ת in Exodus 16:34. Exodus 31:18 is not a problem and was not brought to the attention of the community, so it should be removed from the OP's question.

Comment: @enegue - Because of the current answer, I agree with you - and rolled back the question.  However, I think the topic regarding, "Testimony" is interesting, and will try to open another question.

Comment: @elikakohen Sure. That might be the best way to go.

Comment: @enegue - Done.  Linking because of relationship : https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/27781/in-exodus-what-testimony-was-written-on-the-tablets-of-stone

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the verse you are referring to is a little bit anachronistic and it may actually be referring to the tablets you probably know as the ones that have the ten commandments, although at this point in the story Moses hadn't gone up yet to the mount to receive them from god. Read the [Matthew Poole's Commentary](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/exodus/16-34.htm)

> This text only tells us that Aaron did lay it up, but it doth not determine the time, nor affirm that it was done at this instant

The tablets, according to the bible, contained the Ten Commandments plus other laws or words as the following verses state,

> Exodus 31:18, Exodus 34:1, Exodus 34:27-28

although the interpretations of exactly what was contained are ambiguous. For example read [Adam Clarke Commentary](https://www.studylight.org/commentary/exodus/34-27.html)

> Either a transcript of the whole law now delivered, or the words included from Exodus 34:11; to Exodus 34:26.