# In Exodus, Were the Tablets of Stone a Testimony, or did they Contain Testimony?

Tags: exodus, law, covenant, ten-commandments

<sup>**Closely Related:**

- [What was written on the stone tablets?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/18699/what-was-written-on-the-stone-tablets)

- [Why were the Ten Commandments written on two tablets?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/4381/why-were-the-ten-commandments-written-on-two-tablets)

- [Does anyone know for sure what was written in the tablets mentioned in Exodus 16:34?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/27772/does-anyone-know-for-sure-what-was-written-in-the-tablets-mentioned-in-exodus-16)</sup>

**What does "Testimony" mean in this context?**

- Were the stone tablets themselves a "testimony," immutably written?
- Or, were a "Testimony" AND "Commandments" written on the Tablets of Stone - in the Ark?
- Or, are "Commandments" and "Testimony" essentially synonyms and the same thing?

> **NASB, Exodus 31:18, [Interlinear](http://biblehub.com/interlinear/exodus/31-18.htm)** - When He had finished speaking with him upon Mount Sinai, He gave Moses the ***two tablets of the testimony***, tablets of stone, written by the finger of God.

In Scripture, "Testimonies" and "Commandments" seem like different things altogether:

> **NASB, 1 Kings 2:3** - Keep the charge of the Lord your God, to walk in His ways, to keep His statutes, ***His commandments***, His ordinances, and ***His testimonies***, according to what is written in the Law of Moses ...

Answer (score 1):

The two are the same thing.

The biblical concept of testimony is connected with the Old Testament legal sense of term testimony given in a court of law. 
The term principally derives from the Hebrew yaad, ud, anah [h"n'a] and Greek marturein [marturevw] word groups; 
Testimony would be classed as fact in the same way a commandment is.

Comment: Lyndonia +1, for pointing to the possibility that they might have been considered synonymous, but with different functions.  In this sense, are you saying the commandments themselves are a form of "testimony"?